# How was Ben Rickert able to secure an ISDA agreement?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-short

In *The Big Short*, the Ben Rickert character, played by Brad Pitt, helps a small hedge fund secure an ISDA agreements with institutional banks so the small fund can start trading credit default swaps.

If Rickert is retired, how is he able to secure the $1.5B cap requirement? Was the assumption that Rickert came out of retirement and re-joined an ibank or that he literally had more than $1B in cash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work with ISDAs at a large investment bank every day (since 2014, so granted, after the time period of this movie) but there is no regulatory capital requirement to enter into an ISDA. I believe the $1.5BN referred to in the movie is just the bank’s internal policy (either from a risk standpoint or just based on smaller clients not being worth their time or balance sheet usage). Banks make exceptions to their internal policies (not regulator requirements) for relationship reasons all the time and I believe Ben was enlisted to convince the bank to do so in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The key line from [the script](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://s3.amazonaws.com/thescriptlab/screenplays/2015/the-big-short.pdf) is "*...thank Jared for us*" from Ben Rickert. They're not making a new market, they're taking some of the risk off Jared Vennett and he either agreed to waive the bank's requirements or simply pushed it through as a favour for Ben.

> **INT. LOBBY - DEUTSCHE BANK - DAY 80**
>
> Charlie and Jamie sign an ISDA CONTRACT in the lobby. Ben waits over them.
>
> NOAH, 26, Vennett’s assistant takes the contract.
>
> **NOAH:** *All right. I'll see if I can push it through.*
>
> **BEN:** ***Thanks, Noah. And thank Jared for us.***

Note that the capital requirements are a bank thing, not a regulatory thing, and the "ISDA" isn't a certificate that *allows* trading, just a specific kind of contract that big banks tend to insist on.

> **Capital Requirements for an ISDA Agreement**
>
> There is no regulatory capital to use an ISDA agreement. Still, it is not uncommon for institutions to set their margins and thresholds in banking.
>
> <sub><sup>[Contract Council - ISDAs](https://www.contractscounsel.com/t/us/isda-agreement)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Rickert has **connections**. Moreover, he's considered to be exceedingly good at spotting valuable opportunities, and people are going to **take his advice that into account**.

When Rickert speaks to the banks and tells them that giving them an ISDA is going to work out in the banks' favor, they're going to be much more inclined to deal with that small hedge fund they would have otherwise ignored.

Comment: I assume we're both speaking on speculation here, but banking is a high regulated industry, so it seems unlikely the $1.5B cap requirement was waved  because of his reputation on Wall Street.

Comment: @nipponese _"banking is a high regulated industry"_ It amuses me that you make this statement in the context of The Big Short. It's plot is essentially based on how that assumption is completely false, and it's based on real life events to boot.

Comment: @nipponese - This answer is spot-on.  The Wiki confirms it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Short_(film)#Brownfield_Capital

Comment: @JohnnyBones Not sure how you came to that conclusion. This answer states that Rickert is able to negotiate an ISDA based on his reputation (not shown in the film), and this wikipedia entry states the Brownfield learned CDO deals were not regulated by the SEC so they successfully negotiated deals on AA traunch CDOs without the ISDA.

Comment: @nipponese The point is that Rickert did not need to rejoin an ibank, nor did he need to put up his own money (unsure if he then also bought in, but it was not part of why they asked for his help). He was asked by Brownfield Capital to convince the bank to trade with them (Brownfield Capital). That doesn't require Rickert to grant an ISDA or put up the remainder of 1.5B$ if he can simply convince the bank that they _want_ to trade with Brownfield Capital, based on his unofficial advice and/or recommendation. _How_ he sways them is not shown (AFAIR), _that_ he convinces them is.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the context given in the movie that Rickert had previously been a major trader. This strongly implies he held an ISDA before his "retirement" from the business. So it is quite possible that he had a pre-existing "seat at the table" and didn't need to re-validate to get a new one.

It is also true, as other answers mention, that the stated requirement is an internal policy matter and not a legal standard. So it is also certainly true that Rickert's history would have given him the connection he needs to get access to the platforms for high-value trading. But, given the vague status of the ISDA threshold, the idea that once you have met the threshold, you retain your status, is simpler.